# History behind the name Lakshmi Ganapathi

Tags: gods, ganesha, lakshmi

What is the history behind the name `Lakshmi Ganapathi`

Why is it said that to keep idol of Lakshmi Ganapathi inside the house such that Ganapathi won't allow Lakshmi to leave the house? What was the history behind that?

Answer (score 4):

I happen to search Internet and the first few Google results seems to lead to this text in [this site](http://www.truthstar.com/diwali/why-lakshmi-ganesha-worshiped-together.aspx).

```
Why Lakshmi Ganesha worshiped together?

On the day of Diwali Lord Ganesha is worshiped with Goddess Lakshmi instead Lord Vishnu. There are many questions arises, why Lord Vishnu is not worshiped with Goddess Lakshmi and what is the relation between Lakshmi and Ganesha? The answers of all these questions can be answered by one mythological story. 

Mythological Story

Once upon a time Lord Vishnu and Goddess Lakhmi were having conversation in heaven and Goddess Lakshmi was praising herself and telling Lord Vishnu that she is the most worship worthy in the world and by her grace, a person can get all the pleasures of this world and becomes happiest person. By hearing the self praising by Goddess Laksmi, Lord Vishnu said to her for reducing her ego, “You are having all the qualities, still you did not feel the joy of motherhood till now and for a lady, the motherhood joy is the most important thing in this universe.” 

The comment from Lord Vishnu made Goddess Lakhmi become disheartened and in this pain she went to her friend Goddess Parvati. After listing the problem of Goddess Lakhmi, Parvati asked her, “How can I help you?” Goddess Lakshmi said, “You are having two sons and if you could give me your one son you will still have one son and I could get the grace of motherhood. So, in this situation you can help me out.”

By listing her Goddess Parvati said to her, “I'm having two sons Kartikeya and Ganesha. Kartikeya is having six mouths (Faces) and because of this he needs to eat all the time. My second son Ganesha is very naughty, if I missed to keep eye on him for a bit, he ruined everything. And you cannot stay at one place for a long, so tell me how can you take care of my sons?

By hearing this Goddess Lakshmi said to her, “I'll keep your sons close to my heart and will shower my all love on them either Kartikeya or Ganesha. I can take care both of them. All the servants of heaven will serve them day and night so please give me one of them as my adopted child.”

Maa Parvati knew her both the sons very well so she gave Lord Ganesha to Goddess Lakhmi as her adopted son. Goddess Lakshmi became very happy and said to Goddess Parvati, “From today onwards I'm giving my all accomplishments, luxury and prosperity to my son Ganesha. Also, Riddhi and Siddhi Lord Brahma’s daughters are alike my daughters will be married soon for which I give my word to you. 

I will fulfill all the desires of Ganesha. In all the three loks which person shall not worship Lord Ganesha and do back biting, I will be miles away from him. Whenever my worship will be performed, Lord Ganesha’a worship will be a must. Who will not worship Shri Ganesha along with me, he cannot get Shree or myself. By listening this Maa Parvati become too much happy and handed over her son Ganesh to Laxmi Ji. As such at Deepawali Poojan or Luxmi Poojan, Ganesh Poojan is a must.
```

Though I just reproduced the text as it is from that site, I (please read this as my opinion and my belief) would like to stop believing what ever being read or said. One of the strength of the Hinduism is the vedas which as become its Achilles heel as well due to its limited reach and interpretative nature.  Due to this many customs and mores are born and with passage of time these becomes authoritative.

I always believe in Vedas as the authoritative text though I am unable to interpret it. I have to lay my belief on individuals whom I consider as aacharya or gurus. So, I would not believe this explanation given in the site and also do not worship Lakshmi and Ganapathi together as described in the site as well.

Comment: There is a Shakti Ganapathi also where this Shakti sits on his left thigh indicating she is his wife. Is shakti i.e. Parvati Wife or mother of Ganesha?...These are all modern day mis representations..So, lakshmi Ganapathi is bogus concept and the lakshmi that is mentioned is not the consort of Lord Vishnu.

Comment: I saw a bit similar story in TV serial 'Om Namah Shivay' many years back but that showed that Goddess Lakshmi prayed to Lord Ganesh to become his son and then he took an incarnation as 'Purnanand Ganesh'. There is also a temple of Purnanand Ganesh in Jaipur. Don't know whether this story is valid or not.

Comment: @Aby - Which purana talks about this incident ?

Comment: In north they worship both Lakshmi and Ganesa separately, but maybe simultaneously (not together like Shiva-Parvati and Lakshmi - Narayana, Sita - Raama etc) This rogue concept of Lakshmi Ganapati is modern concept popularised in Andhra pradesh by some narrow minded people. Now, they have Shakti Ganapathi, where Shakti i.e. Parvati is sitting on left thigh of Ganesa. Only, Wives are portrayed as sittung on left thigh of a deity as per scriptures. This is kind of blasphemous concepts like Shakti Ganapathi and Lakshmi Ganapathi being propagated in South India, especially in Andhra pradesh.

Comment: @Krishna I am not sure if this is there in any purana. May be Ganesh Purana or Mudgal Purana has this story. The references synopsis of TV serial can be find out in the following 2 image links in Episode 122 [intelindia.com/mahabharat/images/ons24.jpg] and 123 [intelindia.com/mahabharat/images/ons25.jpg] and site reference for temple address is https://www.here.com/india/jaipur/religious-place/mandir-sri-purnanand-ganesh-ji--356jx7ps-77521fb5e66a08501da2b4c1df2dda6a?msg=Mandir%20Sri%20Purnanand%20Ganesh%20Ji&map=26.92861,75.81525,19,normal

Comment: Btw, in any case, first Goddess Lakshmi's idol is put on the right side and then Lord Ganesha's on left side, such that Goddess Lakshmi is not to be confused as a consort of Lord Ganesha.

Comment: @Aby - North Indians worship the deities of Goddess Lakshmi and Ganesha separately. I think, they place goddess lakshmi to the right. These are two independent deities or idols. North Indians dont have any wrong intention but it would be better if Goddess Lakshmi is worshipped with Lord Vishnu as Goddess will be more pleased when worshipped with Lord Vishnu. Because Goddess Lakshmi, Parvati, Saraswati are the ultimate pativratas...Associating them with other deities whether it is Ganesa or any other deity and worship will tantamount to sin worse then brahma hathya...

Comment: @Aby - But, unfortunately in some parts of south india this blasphemous actions of worshipping Ganesa having Shakti (parvati) or Lakshmi sitting on his left thigh etc which is absolute blasphemy.  BTW, worshipping Goddess Lakshmi should always be with her consort Vishnu, which will give you more benefit as Lakshmi will be more pleased if Vishnu is worshipped and viceversa. Just like you wouldn't want to worship Parvati without Shiva or associate some other deity with Parvati worship. Simple e.g. you will not separte your mother from your father and worship her with  your neighbour, right?

Answer (score 1):

For me Hindu worship is completely symbolic and so are all our Gods and Deities. Lakshmi Ganesha being worshipped together means worshipping wealth along with tolerance and patience. Lakshmi signifies Wealth and Ganpati is symbolic for "vivek' and "vighna-harta". If only wealth is accompanied by these characters it will truly fruitify, or else it can lead to devastation. That's my take!

Comment: Individual opinions cant be pure answers? You need to substantiate your answer with references from genuine scriptures.